# what does this code line in linux do, im a bit confused at the end

Tags: linux, bash, ifconfig

what does the following line of code do when run?

```
ifconfig|grep HWaddr | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 5 -d' '| tr -d ':'
```

Comment: Thanks for editing mate ^^ asked so many questions here but still manage to mess this up

Comment: Why did you tag this with backtrack-linux?

Comment: it's what im using it for guess it is irrelevant atm yeah :>

Answer (score 2):

It does the following:

- Prints out available network interfaces (`ifconfig`)
- Filter out the lines containing their mac addresses (`grep Hwaddr`)
- Limits the output to only the first line (`head -1`)
- In this single line replace multiple spaces with a single space (`tr -s ' '`)
- Filter out the fifth field, while fields are separated by spaces (`cut -f 5 -d' '`)
- Finally delete the `:` in the output (`tr -d ':'`).

What remains is the mac address of the first network interface in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

## In short...

It returns the MAC address without colons.

## Explanation

I hope you are familiar with pipes, let split it up. The first three commands:

```
ifconfig | grep HWaddr | head -1
```

`ifconfig` is a program that displays information about your network interfaces. You feed this to `grep`. `grep` looks for the `HWaddr` pattern: in other words, it will filter the output of `ifconfig` such that only lines containing the string `HWaddr` are retained. Now you feed the output to `head -1` this means that you are only interested in the first match. A possible output of this is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 01:23:45:67:89:ab
```

Now with `tr` you delete characters: since you cannot predict the name of the interfaces (`eth0`), etc. you do not know how much space will be between `eth0` and `Link encap...`. In order to make this determinstic, you use `tr`, so the output after the `tr -s ' '` command is:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 01:23:45:67:89:ab
```

Now we are only interested in the part of the hardware address: since we know that there are four elements before the `HWaddr`, we can `cut` them away:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 01:23:45:67:89:ab
#^1  ^2   ^3             ^4     ^5
```

We do this with `cut -f 5 -d' '` where `-d` is the *delimiter* and we are interested in the fifth *field*. Finally we again remove the colons with `tr -d ':'`.

## Improvement

The command is not really intelligent in the sense that it makes a lot of assumptions. This can be problematic if later someone decides to alter the output of `ifconfig` slightly. An improvement, both performance-wise and when it comes down on making assumption is the following:

```
ifconfig | grep 'HWaddr.*' -o -m 1 | grep -P -o '([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}'  | tr -d ':'
```

Which first prints the `ifconfig` again, filters out the lines with `HWaddr` and prints the remainder of the line of the first match. Then it searches for the pattern of the MAC address with a regex `([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}` and finally it removes the colons (`:`) again.

Although the command looks longer, it only uses four processes (against six original ones) and thus three pipes. Furthermore a pattern is used so if later one changes his mind on how to format the output of `ifconfig` the chances are rather high the script will still identify the MAC address correctly.

Comment: im actually attempting to solve a crackme puzzle, I noticed this line somewhere in the code and I assume that the serial for the puzzle is taken from the Mac address of the machine, however I already assumed that the command removes the points and tried the MAC as a serial but it didnt really work... Anyway thanks a lot for your time !